# How to execute 'coffee' command after installation?

Tags: node.js, terminal, coffeescript, npm

I installed coffee-script as per directions.

```
$ npm install http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master
npm http GET http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master   
npm http 200 http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ms@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json formidable@1.0.11 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json css@1.0.8 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json uglify-js@2.2.5 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm WARN package.json walk@2.2.1 No repository field.   
npm WARN package.json css-parse@1.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json css-stringify@1.0.5 No repository field.
coffee-script@1.6.3 node_modules/coffee-script
└── mkdirp@0.3.5
```

yet when i execute 'coffee' command i get

```
$ coffee
-bash: coffee: command not found
```

What am i doing wrong?

PS: i am doing this on Mac Terminal

EDIT: -

Same problem is occurs when i install `nodemon` the npm install takes place similar to above. But when i input a `nodemon` command on `$` prompt it says `-bash: nodemon: command not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed coffeescript on my mac yeasterday as a matter of fact. Here is how I did it:

First of all, go install [NodeJS](http://NodeJS.org).

Then go in Terminal and type the following: `sudo npm install -g coffee-script`

That's it - If you type in `coffee` in Terminal, it should start without a problem

Answer (score 2):

Anything you want to run as a command (nodemon, coffee, node-inspector) must be installed with `npm install -g the-package-name`. If you use `npm install` it just puts it into your local node_modules directory and won't create the symlink for command line execution.

If you find that you need to use `sudo`, you might want to read this blog post: http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm:

> **what, no sudo?**
>
> I strongly encourage you not to do package management
>   with sudo! Packages can run arbitrary scripts, which makes sudoing a
>   package manager command as safe as a chainsaw haircut. Sure, it's fast
>   and definitely going to cut through any obstacles, but you might
>   actually want that obstacle to stay there.
>
> I recommend doing this once instead:
>
> `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`